# JButton absolute underneath my paint() board

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a poker game where I designed a nice pretty GUI that displays the cards and players. I did it all extending JPanel inside paint() with a lot of g2d.drawImage's and g2d.drawString()'s, with definite x and y locations.

My problem now is that I need to have a couple interactive buttons underneath it.. but whenever I try to add a JButton, it appears top and center. I've used setLocation(x, y) and setLayout(null) and everything I've seen in other replies, but none of them seem to match my need (Or at least I don't have a very well understanding of where to put it)

This is how my code is set up:
pokerserver.java

```
public class pokerserver extends JFrame {

    public pokerserver() {
        add(new drawing());    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(720, 640);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Poker HANGOUTS");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);            
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new pokerserver();    
    }
```

And then in drawing.class

```
public drawing() {      
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(new Color(39,91,46));
    setDoubleBuffered(true);        
    gameCards = new cards();
    gameCards.shuffle();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        seats[i] = -1;

    HQ = new HeadQuarters(this);
    HQ.start();

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);       

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    //All my UI code
    }
```

My last attempt was trying to add

```
   JButton button = new JButton("TEST");
    add(button);
   button.setLocation(10, 500);
```

at the end of public drawing(). I Keep seeing things on layout management, but it's not helping me -- mainly because I'm not sure how to implement it

Here's a screenshot to help visualize what I'm talking about->

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O11C0.png

Trying to get the button underneath. Unless there's a way to add an ActionListener to a drawImage()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your main panel use a BorderLayout.

Then to the "CENTER" you can add your game panel with all your custom painting.

Then create a panel and add the buttons to it. Now you can add this panel to the NORTH of the main panel.

In other words you are not restricted to using a single panel.

Also, custom painting should be done in the paintComponent() method of your panel, NOT the paint() method.

Comment: I saw someone else say that, what is the difference between paintComponent() and paint()? And I'm going to give the panel thing a shot

Comment: paint is responsible for painting the component, its borders and its children. If your painting override does not change border or child painting, then you'll not want to override paint but rather paintComponent. Else you risk mucking with border and child painting with unintended consequences. The tutorials will tell you all this.

Comment: Okay.

As for original question, I think the main issue is my confusion of panels - I understand how to add components to layouts and arrange them that way, but how do I group all my paint's into a panel? At the tutorial, it has panel.add(component), but I'm using g2d.drawImage(image, x, y)?
Sorry, my java swing knowledge is limited because I learned java for Android Dev so I skimmed through this section :P

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you are after, but here are two interpretations.

[image: Buttons over custom painting]  [image: Buttons below custom painting]

I suspect you want the 1st one 'Buttons over custom painting', but as a user I'd prefer the 2nd, with 'Buttons below custom painting'.

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage bg;

    PaintPanel(LayoutManager2 layout) {
        super(layout);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (bg==null) {
            bg = new BufferedImage(500,500,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2 = bg.createGraphics();
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                0,0,Color.RED,500,500,Color.BLUE);
            g2.setPaint(gp);
            g2.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
            g2.dispose();
        }

        g.drawImage(bg,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel buttons = new JPanel(
                    new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
                buttons.setOpaque(false);
                buttons.add(new JButton("Start"));
                buttons.add(new JButton("Stop"));

                PaintPanel pp = new PaintPanel(new BorderLayout());
                pp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));

                pp.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pp);

                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gui.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                gui.add(pp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                gui.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the second one. I figured it out, I wasn't treating my drawing class as it's own JPanel :P I was using a code outline that I used going through a game development tutorial, so the whole components concept was confusing me.. I was trying to make the button inside the drawing class instead of the main one